# How to configure static IPs for a toy MPI cluster?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, centos, virtualbox, hpc

I am developing a minimal teaching example for setting up an MPI cluster using two nodes. I am using VM's in VirtualBox, connected via the 'Host-Only Adapter' network configuration, effectively an isolated network. The same configuration would also be applicable for a small cluster of physical machines on an isolated network.

The goal is to focus on MPI and keep the example as simple as possible, avoiding the use of DHCP, DNS, or setting the address manually after boot. Using the other internal network configurations in VirtualBox, I get a dynamic IP from the DHCP in VirtualBox. But in the example I'm developing, I want to use static IP and 'Host-Only' maps most closely to the physical hardware configuration.

I have configured a static IP for eth0 in `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
gateway 192.168.56.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And I have entered the hosts on both machines in `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.56.101  ISTC-1
192.168.56.102  ISTC-2
```

I can force the interface to come up manually after boot by running:

```
$sudo ifup eth0
```

But this seems sloppy. I could try to hack this into startup scripts, but I'm looking for best-practices so I can write a good example.

- How do I cause these interfaces to come up with the specified IP automatically?
- Would this be different under CentOS?

Ubuntu 14.0.4
VirtualBox 4.3.20
MacOS 10.10.5 host

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS you need to edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-XXXXX` file that XXXX for example in my system is `enp3s0` and on your system may be different and insert your configurations. You can use this template (these are minimal configurations you need for IPv4):

```
su -l root
cat > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0 << EOF
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.1.25
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.254
NAME=enp3s0
ONBOOT=yes
EOF
```

`/etc/hosts` file is the same as debian.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
auto eth0
```

to the /etc/network/interfaces and now it works...